# Using delay with HTML or text setting doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have strange problem with the delay function here using the HTML function with it.

I set an HTML text by using `$( '#element').html( 'Hello World');`

After setting the text I want to get this text disappear in 3 seconds.

So next line I wrote:

```
$('#element').delay( 3000).html( '&nbsp');
```

This one doesn't work, it sets the HTML to `&nbsp` without waiting the 3 seconds, it looks like jQuery is skipping the delay function. Using this with fadeOut for example works fine. I guess this has something to do with this queue thing in delay.

But why doesn't this work. Its a pretty simple, wait 3 seconds then run the HTML function.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*delay()* defaults to the animation queue, for effects like *fadeOut()*, etc.  You should use *setTimeout()* instead:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $("#element").html('&nbsp;');
}, 3000);
```

From http://api.jquery.com/delay/:

> jQuery.delay() is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects and such, and is not a replacement for JavaScript's native **[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)** function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Comment: To be more accurate, `.delay()` applies to *any* queue, it just *defaults* to the animation queue :)

Comment: Thanks this one is working now.

One more question: does this work on all browsers? im not sure if window.setTimeout will work in all IE and FF versions.

Comment: @NovumCoder: *window.setTimeout()* goes way back to JavaScript 1.0 and was adopted by IE in IE 5 (I think).  I've yet to discover a browser that doesn't implement it, and now it's part of the proposed  [HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers)

Answer (score 16):

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) isn't a queued function.  If you want it to happen in order in the animation queue, you'll have to [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) it yourself, like this:

```
$('#element').delay(3000).queue(function(n) { 
  $(this).html('&nbsp'); n();
});
```

If you're not chaining animations or anything like this, use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) or [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.setInterval) (whichever is appropriate to the situation) directly, [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is [just a wrapper](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue.js#L83) for [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) and there's no reason to use extra code/complexity when there's no need.