# multiple Html Methods on the same selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to run this code, but when it runs the text its already "Welcome back" and i want it to be 'Hi!' first and then 'Welcome Back'
If anyone knows any way to change this please tell me.

```
$(Animation)
.text('Hi!')
.slideUp(600)
.delay(600)
.text('Welcome Back')
.slideDown(600)
.delay(600)
.slideUp(600)
```

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3675988/5121816), `delay()` defaults to the animation queue. This is why you see your `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` happening correctly, but not the text change. For `text()`, you will have to `queue()` it in a different way, or use `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `delay` method is only for queued items (mostly animation) in jQuery. That's why you see delay between animations correctly, but not between changing text. If you want to do a change like this you will need to use `setTimeout`:

```js
$("div").text('Hi!').slideUp(600);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("div")
        .text('Welcome Back')
        .delay(600)
        .slideDown(600)
        .delay(600)
        .slideUp(600);
}, 600);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Read more about [seTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/).